# How to load driver dynamically for Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am loading drivers dynamically for JDBC. It works fine, however this `DriverManager` becomes useless when I try to open a hibernate session

```
org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded
```

Here is the code

```
    public class TestHibernateSessionFactory {


        public void test() throws MalformedURLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException { 
        URL u = new URL("jar:file:/C:\\Users\\...\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar!/");
        String classname = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { u });
        Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName(classname, true, ucl).newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new DriverLoader(d));


        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "admin", "password"); 

    // this is the proof that DriverManager loaded and works fine
        System.out.println("CONNECTION OBJECT WORKS FINE: " + con);

    // Now I want to try this same technique with hibernate     
        Session session = null; 
        Transaction tx = null; 

        SessionFactory sf = buildSessionFactory("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "admin", "password"); 

// ERROR  Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded  WHY ??? 
            session = sf.openSession(); 
            System.out.println(session);     
        }

        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(String myUrl, String myUser, String myPass) {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", myUrl);
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", myUser);
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", myPass); 
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop"); 

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry(); 

            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    }
```

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't it work with hibernate, but works with jdbc?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346826/database-driver-class-dynamic-loading and see Jobs answer, it might help you

Comment: Thank you. This is a real answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the Hibernate will attempt to load the driver from the context (current thread) classloader and it doesn't have the driver. The first part works because you use the classloader that has the driver to create a connection.

The solution could be to use manipulate the context classloader. Just don't forget to clean it up when methods using the loaded driver exit.

Comment: Thank you very much +1. Could you please share some code

Answer (score 1):

The approach to your problem could be something like this:

Idea is to have your own classloader and use that `ClassLoader` class of yours before initializing your `Hibernate SessionFactory`

Like this:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myOwnClassLoader);
```

Though this is not one of the best solutions to address your problem, that is how it is. Though [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1002728) is an incomplete discussion, it is still useful enough to give you pointers to proceed.

Hope this helps!!!