# Database driver-class dynamic loading

Tags: java, classloader

I want to develop a DB-Agnostic application in java. I have chosen hibernate as ORM. The problem with jdbc is that , it is just an interface and we need the driver class of the db in the class path.  Since the database should be configurable i have to go for  loading the driver class of DB dynamically. (User should keep the driver class in a folder and it should be loaded dynamically )
Below is my code.

```
File driverJar = new File("E:\\Jomon\\backup_2017_05_25\\2.2\\WS\\2.2_1\\lib\\Drivers\\postgresql-42.1.1.jar");
URL[] urls = new URL[] { driverJar.toURL() };
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls,DBUtils.class.getClassLoader());
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver", true, classLoader);
```

No error till now.
But after this, while initializing hibernate connection, I am getting error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver.

May I know what is the problem here.

Comment: You're missing the Postgres driver from your classpath, as the error indicates

Comment: I have chosen this way of class loading just to avoid keeping the jar in classpath along with my runnable jar.

If I went for that , if the application user planing to use oracle than postgres, I must give another runnable jar with oracle driver in its class path, and that is not possible in my case.

What I am doing is , let the user to keep the jar in a folder, provide the path of jar, and driver class name n another configuration file and load the class dynamically during the initialization face of the application.

Comment: But you're hard-coding the file names in your code. If you really want it to be dynamic, you should loop over all Jar files in a folder

Comment: This is just a snippet prepared just to ask the doubt :)

Comment: even if I try Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") immediately after Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver", true, classLoader);, I am getting the same error

Comment: If you place the same Jar file in your current classpath, what happens?

Comment: It works , but I cannot predict what driver user wants oracle or postgres ... etc

Comment: I understand that, so the issue is how you're building the new classpath

Comment: What I am planing to give is a runnable jar.(The client is not ready to run it via CMD in windows )
. If we are ran the application via cmd we could mention the class path with required jars in it.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the solution by myself, 
The problem here is , I have created a new classloader and loaded the jar into it.

The hibernate is searching for driver class in system class loader , not in the user defined class loaders.

The problem here can be solved by load the jar into system class loader as below.

```
File driverJar = new File("E:\\Jomon\\backup_2017_05_25\\2.2\\WS\\2.2_1\\lib\\Drivers\\postgresql-42.1.1.jar");
URL myJarFile = new URL("jar", "", "file:" + driverJar.getAbsolutePath() + "!/");
URLClassLoader sysLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

Class sysClass = URLClassLoader.class;
Method sysMethod = sysClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
sysMethod.setAccessible(true);
sysMethod.invoke(sysLoader, new Object[] { myJarFile });

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver", true, classLoader); // Now no error in this line.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will always to attempt the load the driver from the current thread classloader and in your case, it doesn't have the driver.

You own class loader works fine and just before you initialize sessionFactory ,set your custom loader into contextClassLoader like this.

```
    File f = new File( "E:\\Jomon\\backup_2017_05_25\\2.2\\WS\\2.2_1\\lib\\Drivers\\postgresql-42.1.1.jar" );
    URLClassLoader urlCl = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] { f.toURL() }, System.class.getClassLoader() );
    Class postGreDriver = urlCl.loadClass( "org.postgresql.Driver" );
    System.out.println( postGreDriver.newInstance() );

    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(postGreDriver);

    //Hibernate can start

    //you should restore your old classloader when hibernate services end
```

This may not be the best solution. Have got this snippet from this  [discussion](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1002728)

Hope this helps!!!